# Show messageBox from class behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

I have ASPX.net web application with webpage and class behind. From webpage I am creating object and then running several methods in class behind. I am facing problem, that I need to show MessageBox from class behind, but I am not able to do it. I tried to add public method to MasterPage file, but I am not able to access that method.

```
public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    }
```

Or just a simple version :

```
private void showMessage(string text)
{
    string script = "alert(\"" + text + "\");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
}
```

Second code sample has problem with "this" first parameter.

Anyone please help me, how to do it? I need to also create Yes/No question based on this [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx) so anyone can help please how to achieve?

Thank you

Comment: try this `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showalert", "alert('"+ sb.ToString() + "');", true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

It will write the script on the rendered page. and show the alert box.

Comment: Can you be please more specific where this code use and how?